# Simplest, smallest PHP account system

Tags: php, mysql, forum, user-accounts

There's an interesting example of someone managing to create a PHP script for a forum which only takes up 1kb: http://www.nerdparadise.com/blogs/blake/6034/

I wonder if there a similar tiny script(s) which could handle user accounts (and could perhaps be added to the above forum script). I'm thinking each account would hold just a username, email and password.

Comment: I would just recommend you don't use that script:). It needs a lot of code to make it survive in real world. Just try the link that the author provided - most likely you'll have to kill your browser after clicking it:).

Answer (score 4):

```
Magic quotes need to be enabled to prevent SQL injection!
```

LOL, don't even think of using this.